# Solving TSP using Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Is it possible to solve Travelling Salesman Problem or Multi-TSP using Neo4j?

I have to find an optimal path which covers all the nodes. I have tried finding all possible paths and then find the minimum distance. The execution time increases exponentially as the number of nodes are increased.

Comment: I'd start with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem, the programming language shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

The Traveling Salesman Problem is the [quintessential example of an NP-hard problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Computational_complexity).   So the execution time **does not increase exponentially** as, if it did, it would be polynomial.   It's actually probably worse than that.  :)

These algorithms aren't in neo4j by default.   Can you do them with java and cypher?  Yes, sure.   Should you do them?  The practical advice that I've seen is that once you get up to about 100 cities, it's starting to get impractical to do this.  Research systems with the best algorithms are solving TSP for 30,000 - 50,000 cities right now.   Personally, I wouldn't advise trying it within two orders of magnitude of the research systems right now unless you have a lot of hardware and computing you can throw at it (e.g., via something like leased EC2 computing).

In terms of algorithms, there is the [Held-Karp algorithm](http://ucilnica1213.fmf.uni-lj.si/pluginfile.php/11706/mod_resource/content/0/HELDKarpAlgoritemZaPTP_clanek.pdf) which is O(n^2 * 2^n).   Ouch.    [Wikipedia has other suggestions as well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem#Exact_algorithms).

So, I think from a theoretical computer science perspective, yes this is doable, you have to write it yourself, the algorithm is very complex (in the sense that it takes a long time to execute and grows quickly).  From a practical engineering standpoint, it's totally doable for fewer than 100 cities, and it's going to be extremely difficult and expensive to try it with n >= 10,000 or so.

See also [this related stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25673673/neo4j-traveling-salesman).